# What is the theory of finding roots of a polynomial equation by looking at the factors of the $a_n$ and $a_0$ term called?

Tags: functions, polynomials, factoring

This is commonly taught in high schools in the context of factoring polynomials. I remember this method even has its own wikipedia page (with a proof) but I forget what was the theory called. Could anybody remind me of the name?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [rational roots (or zeros) theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). I wrote this up a while back (maybe you will find it helpful):

[image]